# Items in a library have wrong content type

Tags: 2013, list

I created a library containing 6 custom content types derived from some base ones:
Article (base: Wiki Page)
MyDocument (base: Document)
MyDocumentSet (base: DocumentSet)
MyPresentation (base: Document)
MyImage (base: Image)
MyVideo (base: Video)

I customized the list view so it could show the ContentType column.

The problem is when I create MyDocument or MyPresentation items, the ContentType column show that they have 'Article' content type. For others everything's fine.
The most interesting thing that when I change the default content type for the library in SP designer, newly created MyDocument and MyPresentation take it instead of 'Article'

I checked ContentType IDs in elements.xml of each item - everything's correct there.

What could the problem be? The sharepoint version is 2013. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Document templates will carry a lot of xml data with them and sometimes it won't get overwritten. You can see them when using word: File --> Info: Inspect Document --> Check for issues: Inspect Document You will see what data this document carries within. And you can delete this information also in this view. Remove that data and upload template for the content type again.